# Datasets for clustering algorithms

Tags: dataset, data-mining, cluster-analysis

I am asked to give a lecture on clustering algorithms for an audience that is not very technical. With that in mind, I wanted to do a simple exercise where I will ask the audience to identify groups from a dataset. However, I cannot find good datasets that could be usable for this purpose.

Is there a dataset of customers and some products they have bought that I can use for this purpose? Or any other dataset that might look suitable!

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a simple geo location database for example all cities in germany. I think you can find it for free. Or you can look for the NASA sky data. Would be nice to cluster too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Ta-Feng dataset containing 4 months of transactions. Got it from Prof. Chun Nan himself. It is now stored in my dropbox folder: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tsd5zd8a7afmzs7/D11-02.ZIP?dl=0 The first line of each file shows the column names in Chinese. In English is:
Date; Membership Card ID; Product Category; Product Code; Quantity; Total Transaction Amount (in TWD)